# strange behavior in vim with negative look-behind

Tags: regex, vim, find, negative-lookbehind

So, I am doing this search in vim:

```
/\(\(unum\)\|\(player\)=\)\@<!\"1\"
```

and as expected it does not match lines that have:

```
player="1"
```

but matches lines that have:

```
unum="1"
```

what am i doing wrong? isn't the atom to be negated all of this: `\(\(unum\)\|\(player\)=\)`

naturally just doing: `/\(\(unum\)\|\(player\)=\)` matches `unum=` or `player=`.

Comment: `echo matchstr("unum=", '\(\(unum\)\|\(player\)=\)')` outputs `unum`, not `unum=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern is

```
\(
    \(unum\)\|
    \(player\)=
\)\@<!"1"
```

which is equivalent to

```
\(
    \(unum\)\|
    \(player=\)
\)\@<!"1"
```

And it must be

```
\(
    \(unum\|player\)=
\)\@<!"1"
```

Just remove one closing and one opening parenthesis.

And, writing `\"` is strange: in situations where you have to escape `"` you also need to escape slash.